# Update Existing Field Editing Changes Don't Persist in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I toggle editing on a layer, open the attribute table -> Field Calculator -> Check 'Update Existing Field' -> Select 'myfield' in dropdown -> type...

```
myfield / 60
```

-> Hit 'Ok' -> Save Edits -> Stop Editing

The changes seem to appear in the attribute table, but when I close the attribute table and re-open, the changes are gone. When I export the result to geojson, the changes aren't there either.

Any ideas on how to persist these edits short of making a new field? This is on QGIS 3.4 Madeira, Windows 10.

EDIT:
I cannot even persist changes in a new field: the result is all null

[image]

Comment: What vector format are you using, what are the field types of `AS_Time` and `AS_Minute`? Also have you tried to use `"AS_Time" / 60`?

Comment: You can try `to_int( "AS_Time" ) / 60`. However, it would be highly suggested accomplishing everything that was suggested by @ahmadhanb.Problem is probably about the field type either `"AS_Time"` or `"AS_Minutes"`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Field calculator on geosjon? It could be related to a bug discussed here:
[latest version of QGIS fails to edit attribute table of GeoJSON file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319450/latest-version-of-qgis-fails-to-edit-attribute-table-of-geojson-file)

QGIS bug is still open today, here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20760#change-97363